# Paramiko - Handle network failure during exec_command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm writing a script with Paramiko and I would like to handle network error if it happens during `exec_command`.

With the sample code below, if there is a network error from the beginning, it works well. The function is trying to execute itself until the connection is established.

But if the error happens in the middle of the function, it doesn't raise an exception and returns an empty string instead.

```
def execute(command, connection):
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(connection.host, username=connection.username, password=connection.password)
        log("Command: "+command, YELLOW)

        dummy_stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("source ~/.bash_profile > \
                                                          /dev/null; "+command)
        err = stderr.read()
        res = stdout.read()
        client.close()

        if err.strip() == "OK":
            log(err.strip(), BLANK)
            return err.strip()
        elif err != '':
            log(err.strip(), RED)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            log(res.strip(), BLANK)
            return res.strip()

    except:
        log("Network failure. Trying again ...", RED)
        return execute(command, connection)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for an active connection after you finish reading a command output:

```
client.get_transport().is_active()
```